# Python2 error: global name "self' is not defined"

Tags: python, self

Me da el siguiente error:

> global name 'self' is not defined

¿Cómo haría para que la última línea de este código esté dentro de la función y dentro de la misma clase?

Aquí el código:

```
class default():
 
  def getRequest (self, url, referUrl, userAgent, xRequestedWith=""):
        UTF8 = 'utf-8'
        headers = {'User-Agent':userAgent, 'Referer':referUrl, 'X-Requested-With': xRequestedWith, 'Accept':"text/html", 'Accept-Encoding':'gzip,deflate,sdch', 'Accept-Language':'en-US,en;q=0.8'} 
        
        request = urllib2.Request(url.encode(UTF8), None, headers)

        try:
            response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
            
            if response.info().getheader('Content-Encoding') == 'gzip':
                print ("Content Encoding == gzip")
                buf = StringIO( response.read() )
                f = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=buf)
                link1 = f.read()
            else:
                link1=response.read()
        except:
            link1 = ""
        
        link1 = str(link1).replace('\n','')
        return(link1)

  USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3730.0 Safari/537.36"   

  server_certificate = self.getRequest("https://widevine-pagina-vod.video.net/licenser/getcertificate", "https://www.pagina.com", USER_AGENT)
```

---

En realidad quiero el certificado para usarlo en kodi en esta línea:

```
play_item.setProperty('inputstream.adaptive.server_certificate', server_certificate);
```

Entonces, ¿cómo quedaría dicha línea?

Comment: La última línea del código mostrado no está dentro de la función, por lo que no tiene acceso a `self`. Pero está dentro de la clase, lo que a lo mejor tampoco tiene mucho sentido. Igual lo que quieres es ponerla fuera de la clase pero haciendo `ejemplo = default(); ejemplo.getRequest(...etc...)`

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda, en este caso como haria para que la ultima linea de este codigo este dentro de la funcion y dentro de la misma clase????

Answer (score 0):

No se si esto podrá ayudarte, pero voy a suponer que necesitas que cada vez que se crea la clase "default" se ejecuten las líneas que hacen referencia al server_certificate. He supuesto también que luego quieres acceder a server_certificate, por ello lo he añadido como atributo de la clase.

```py
class default():
    def __init__(self):
        self.server_certificate = None
        self.setServerCertificate()
        
    def getRequest(self, url, referUrl, userAgent, xRequestedWith=""): ... 
        # Esta funcion sigue igual

    # Si esto se tiene que ejecutar en creación de la clase, llamaría a esta función dentro del método init.
    def  setServerCertificate(self):
        self.USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3730.0 Safari/537.36"

        self.server_certificate = self.getRequest("https://widevine-pagina-vod.video.net/licenser/getcertificate",
                                         "https://www.pagina.com", USER_AGENT)
```

No puedo ayudarte mucho más, ya que no se exactamente como lo quieres resolver, ni desde donde se hacen las llamadas, pero espero que sea de utilidad.

Un saludo, aquí estoy para cualquier cosa.

Comment: disculpa si no fui explicito en realidad quiero el certificado para usarlo en kodi en esta linea play_item.setProperty('inputstream.adaptive.server_certificate', server_certificate); entonces como quedaria dicha linea, y muchas gracias por tu respuesta